# How can I use iPhone as a roaming authenticator for webauthn?

Tags: iphone, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I would like to use my iPhone as a *roaming authenticator* using FaceID when authenticating to web sites using webauthn.

I have upgraded my iPhone iOS to version 14.0.1. I use [webauthn.io](https://webauthn.io/) as an example web site.

#### Use case

I want to register my iPhone as a *roaming authenticator*  on a web site, such that I can *authenticate* with it, both

- when visiting a web site with my private laptop, but also
- so that I can *authenticate* with it when visiting the same web site on a work laptop.

#### Registration

As I want to use the device as a *roaming authenticator*, I assume that I should choose **Cross Platform** as *Authenticator Type* on [webauthn.io](https://webauthn.io/).

But it seems that I can only register the iPhone as authenticator when **not** chosing **Cross Platform** as *Authenticator Type*.

Now webauthn is new for me, is the problem on the web site I test with or is this not supported on iPhone, or how can I setup the iPhone as a roaming authenticator?

Comment: I don't believe this functionality is available for the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the project's issue system, this type of workflow is not supported by the standard (yet). It is not a specific problem with iPhone.

Please refer to this issue:

https://github.com/duo-labs/webauthn.io/issues/21

Note that a similar workflow recently became possible on some Android phones. However it is implemented via CaBLE, as mentioned in the above linked issue. CaBLE is cloud-assisted Bluetooth Low Energy - which is Google's own technology, and not part of the WebAuthn standard.